# What is the best way to check where/who a HTTP request has come from using PHP?

Tags: php, api, security, http

I am currently building a shopify app which I have also built an API along side it. I am wanting to somehow make sure only certain website's have access to the API. I was thinking of checking the origin or refer but these can easily be faked in a HTTP request. I also thought of giving each website an access token of some sort but then they could give this out to other websites to then use the API?

So my question is, what is the most secure way to check where the request has come from?

Comment: How about a callback, like Paypal IPN?

Comment: How about tying api key to the host `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` ?

Comment: this may shed some [light](http://talks.codegram.com/http-authentication-methods#/intro)